# Why does the location of an element is different from the clicking coordinates using selenium python robot framework?

Tags: python, selenium, robotframework

i want to click a point at known coordinates on the canvas and assert that the created point is at the clicked coordinates only.

for doing it, i click the element using selenium robot framework keyword

```
Click Element At Coordinates  locator  -50  -50
```

here locator is the canvas element

the above creates an element at xoffset -50 and yoffset -50.

now to assert that the element is created at -50 -50 i use below code in selenium python

```
point_element = driver.find_element_by_xpath("//[text()='name']")
    location = point_element.location
    assert location['x'] == x_offset and location['y'] == y_offset
```

Here variables x_offset and y_offset is -50 -50

Now this gives an assertionerror since location['x'] is 480 and location['y'] is 120 whereas the element originally is clicked at coordinates -50 -50.

how can i get the matching coordinates. is there something that i am missing. could someone help me with this. thanks.

Comment: You say "the above creates an element at xoffset -50 and yoffset -50.", but the `Click Element ...` would only click, not create an element.

Comment: yes but i click on a button that draws some element onto the canvas. and then move the cursor to this -50 -50 position to click

Comment: You are mixing relative position with absolute coordinates. You should, 1. Get initial coordinates, 2. Move element, 3. Get new coordinates, 4. Compare delta calculation. Maybe is better to use only on Python side.

Comment: could you provide the rough snippet i shall check that...python is okay too. thanks